# UML Representing an anonymous class in class diagram?

Tags: java, oop, uml

How would one represent a Java anonymous class in a UML class diagram?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/676092/583592 maybe this can help, as this answer shows an example for Java.

Comment: @KevinJalbert, nice, saw it after posting. apparently there's a single source reference for this issue :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Inner (nested) classes are represented in UML with an association
>   adorned with a crossed circle.

#### Illustration:

[image: UML inner class]

#### Source:

- [*UML Class Diagrams for Java Programmers*](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=336264&seqNum=3), by *Robert C. Martin* on *InformIT*.

Comment: The link has even concrete info for the `anonymous` inner classes the poster asked about, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/676092/583592.

Comment: It is by far not enough. And it is not up to the standard. You are showing here the containment relationship of the anonymous class, without other relationships.

Answer (score 3):

There are two really anonymous classes in Java
First is the non-named inner class. Such as:

```
class BGThread<T>{...}
...
class TitleEditDlg{
    new BGThread<Props>(cont, true) {
        @Override
        public Props run() {
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```

A citation from UML standard 2.5 (p.149):

> The standard notation for an anonymous InstanceSpecification of an
>   unnamed Classifier is an underlined colon (‘:’).

So, as for anonymous java class, you should create a class block with only `:` as name and connect the container class to it twice - by container relationship and by one-direction arrow without a dot. From the other side, the `:` block should connect to the parent class.

---

According to the same source, an `Anonymous Bound Class`, that is the second anonymous class we meet in Java, but often do not notice it, when you use a template/generic class, as in

```
class BGThread<T>{...}
...
class TitleEditDlg{
   BGThread<String> newThread= new BGThread<String>();
}
```

can be shown by two ways:

- As `bind` dependency, with substitution on it.
- As an intermediate class, with the name of the parent class and substitution in angle brackets. Notice, here the class is anonymous, but the attribute has a name. So, this way you are showing more information.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to represent a JavaScript object literal in a class diagram (I know it doesn't make much sense...)and I found this post.

I'd contribute with this link and image.
Ciao.

http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html

[image]